# Deny role from connecting to a certain voice channel [discord.py]

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

This is my code for changing a voice channels permissions:

```
permissions = ctx.channel.overwrites_for(team_role)
permissions. = False # What to write after permissions. ?
await channel.set_permissions(team_role, overwrite=permissions)
```

In line 2 I do not know what to write after `permissions.` in text channels it would be `permissions.read_messages` but I do not know what I should do for not allowing a role to connect to that voice channel. Where could I find that or what would that be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After looking around, I couldn't find this in the docs but I just tried it out and it worked, its permissions.connect to deny someone permissions from connecting to a voice channel